# How to mock bool/bit data on view?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I what to mock bool data in a view SQL Server, my query is here:

[image: sql server query]

but when I run my .NET application I receive an error that .NET can not implicit convert `system.int32` to `system.bool`. My .NET code is here:

[image: .net code class]

Then my question is: How do I mock a boolean data on a SQL Server view?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Don't paste pictures of code, we cant cut and paste and modify images into an answer, they cant be debugged, and they are generally annoying as you have to click off the page. Put your code (in both cases) inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly convert it as follows:

```
select permiteTrocarSenha = convert(bit, 1)
```